# cv2.matchShapes() always returns 0.0

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I've been trying to compare contours of a livefeed with the contours of an image using cv2.matchshapes(). I'm using the following

[image]

This is the code I'm using (sorry for the sloppy formatting):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
img1 = cv2.imread('prod1_gray.jpg',0)

ret, thresh_img1 = cv2.threshold(img1, 230, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
thresh_img1 = cv2.dilate(thresh_img1, kernel, iterations=2)
thresh_img1 = cv2.erode(thresh_img1, kernel, iterations=3)

_, contours_img1, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh_img1, 
cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
if contours_img1:
    cntimg = contours_img1[0]



while True:
    _, frame  = cap.read()
    frame = frame[127:470, 80:550]
    frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(frame_gray, 230, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
    thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=2)
    thresh = cv2.erode(thresh, kernel, iterations=3)

    _, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    if contours:
        cnt = contours[0]
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        if area > 30:
            cv2.drawContours(frame, contours, -1, (0, 255, 255), 3)

        ret = cv2.matchShapes(cnt[0], cntimg[0], 1, 0.0)
        print(ret)


    cv2.imshow("Original", frame)
    cv2.imshow("thresh",thresh)
    cv2.imshow("gray", frame_gray)
    cv2.imshow("prod1",img1)


    k = cv2.waitKey(30)
    if k == 27:
        cv2.imwrite("pen.jpg", img1)
        print("cntimg, ",cntimg[0])
        print("cnt, ",cnt[0])
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

For some reason, the cv2.matchShapes() always outputs 0.0, wether nothing is in front of the camera (no contours) or a random object like a pen:

[image: pen]

While it should be outputting a number, since the pen has a different shape than the original object.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: from the code posted here, what I can tell is that you  match a point against another point.... which results in 0... cnt and cntImage are already an array of points... and when you do [0] you get the first point... try wihtout [0]. Also, no points = no moments = no difference = 0.0 so it makes sense that it return 0  in the case of no contour.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I removed the [0] and now I get an extremely large number, no matter what I put in front of the camera. My ret is 1.7976931348623157e+308

Comment: I would have to try and see, can you post the two contours or images?

Comment: https://imgur.com/BnwtQGp
https://imgur.com/zL4LEHe
What might be the problem is that img cnt outputs a lot of arrays, while cntimg only outputs two.

Comment: did some tests without the images, it seems that it is badly coded.... and if by any chance one of the huMoments is 0.... it gives that number, even if the method 2 which does not divide :S try checking with cv2.HuMoments(cv2.moments(cnt)) if one of them is 0

Comment: None of the huMoments are 0.. But after I removed the [0] as you suggested in your first comment, matchShapes() returns 1.7976931348623157e+308.. Do you have any idea what I should change in my code to make it work?
EDIT: I found out that the cv2.HuMoments(cv2.moments(cntimg)) are all 0

Comment: I found the problem, the image I was comparing to was bad. I made a new image and now it's working fine! Thanks for your help.

Comment: no problem, good that you solve it :)

Answer (score 1):

When 0.0 is returned this means that the 2 shapes that are compared are exactly the same.
Now I'm going to assume you're not accidentely comparing the image with itself.

The only other solution I see is that you use cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL for your contours.
Now what sometimes happens is that the findcontours function will find all contour (I know right? crazy world) and stores them hierarchycally.
Now sometimes one of those contours is just the outerside of your image.
This means the shape of the frame itself.
If this happens in your case it would actually make sense that it results in 0.0 upon matching as your frame is exactly the same.

Now, I don't know why as I am not an expert by any means. But I'd advice you to test it with another retrievalMode let's say: cv2.RETR_TREE.
You could also test this with an imshow() of your results, see what contours get marked.
Let me know what you find.